# Azure Mobile Service: SQL database search

Tags: c#, database, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I have in my mobile Service a table called AccountData. I want to include a simple search for Persons. Currently I have this:

```
return await _personTable.Where(Person => Person.Name == searchstring || Person.Email == searchstring).ToListAsync();
```

I want to go a step further, so it is not necessary to enter the exact same name...

Comment: have you tried using `.Contains()` function : `.Where(Person => Person.Name.Contains(searchstring))`

Comment: Great! Have not thought that would be so easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As har07 wrote:

> have you tried using .Contains() function : .Where(Person => Person.Name.Contains(searchstring))

It works!